# Software recommendation to convert DOCX files to PDF on CentOS 5

Tags: pdf, conversion, centos, docx

I have a some DOCX files I want to convert to PDF. Is there a way to do this using CentOS 5.7 x64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenOffice (maybe LibreOffice) should be installed (assuming you have a GUI) if that is 3+ then that will open docx files that can be exported to PDF